# sql server: using variable order by in row_number()

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use variable order by in row_number, it works when each case has a single column defined with no asc, or desc. but it doesn't work when I define more than one column or use asc or desc.

this works:

```
select top(@perpage) *,row_number()
 over (order by
case @orderby when 'updated' then date_edited
              when 'oldest' then date_added  
  end
) 
as rid from
(select * from ads) a
 where rid>=@start and rid<@start+@perpage
```

but I want to do this:

```
select top(@perpage) *,row_number()
 over (order by
case @orderby when 'updated' then date_edited, user_type desc
              when 'oldest' then date_added, user_type desc
              when 'newest' then date_added desc, user_type desc
              when 'mostexpensive' then price desc, user_type desc
              when 'cheapest' then pricedesc, user_type desc
              when '' then user_type desc
  end
) 
as rid from
(select * from ads) a
 where rid>=@start and rid<@start+@perpage
```

Comment: CASE - single value expression. You should use one CASE expression per each "virtual" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select top(@perpage) *,row_number()
 over (order by
case @orderby when 'updated' then date_edited end,
case @orderby when 'oldest' then date_added end,
case @orderby when 'newest' then date_added end desc,
case @orderby when 'mostexpensive' then price end desc,
case @orderby when 'cheapest' then price end,
user_type desc
) 
as rid from
(select * from ads) a
 where rid>=@start and rid<@start+@perpage
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
select top(@perpage) *,row_number()
 over (order by
case @orderby when 'updated' then date_edited
              when 'oldest' then date_added
end,
case @orderby when 'newest' then date_added
end desc,
case @orderby when 'mostexpensive' then -price
              when 'cheapest' then pricedesc

end, 
  user_type desc
) 
as rid from ads a
where rid>=@start and rid<@start+@perpage
```

Comment: as I recall, the `-` makes unexpected things happen with 0, just a vague hunch.

Comment: @Jodrell no, but a - on datetime would cause problems, so you are half right

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` is an expression that returns a single value. Since the second sort column is always the same, then you can just have:

```
 over (order by
case @orderby when 'updated' then date_edited
              when 'oldest' then date_added
              when 'newest' then date_added desc
              when 'mostexpensive' then price desc
              when 'cheapest' then pricedesc
  end, user_type desc
)
```

(When `@orderby` is equal to `''`, then the case expression will produce `NULL` for every row - but since all `NULL`s sort together, this is fine)

Just noticed that not all of your columns names suggest compatible types - in which case this may be better:

```
 over (order by
case @orderby when 'updated' then date_edited
              when 'oldest' then date_added
  end,
  case @orderby 
        when 'newest' then date_added
  end desc,
  case @orderby
        when 'mostexpensive' then price
  end desc,
  case @orderby
        when 'cheapest' then price
  end asc,
  user_type desc
)
```

You can have a separate `CASE` statement for each data type and asc/desc combination needed - and as stated above, each one will just produce `NULL`s for any `@orderby` value not mentioned.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani - have you seen the updated version? `asc` and `desc` aren't part of specifying a value - so they can't be part of the `CASE` expression